# Python Flask не грузит страницу

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return '<p> hello world </p>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Идет долгая загрузка, после чего браузер выдает ошибку. Как исправить?

Comment: А вы уверены, что запрос вообще доходит до фласка? Может, он отклоняется каким-нибудь роутером или межсетевым экраном?

Comment: Раньше работало, и в один день перестало. Понятия не имею почему так произошло.